# How to write/read jagged arrays in a HDF5 file using the C++ API?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I've multiple `std::vector` of different sizes containing floats. I would like to write/read them all as a jagged array in a HDF5 file (ideally one by one using hyperslabs since I can't hold all vectors in memory simultaneously). I believe I should use a regular array with each of its elements being of a variable length datatype, but all the examples I found were C examples. My code looks as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

int main() {
  std::vector<float> v1 {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
  std::vector<float> v2 {0.4, 0.5};

  H5::VarLenType array_type (H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);

  hsize_t dimensions[1] = {2};
  H5::DataSpace dataspace (1, dimensions);

  H5::H5File file ("jarray.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
  H5::DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet("jarray", array_type, dataspace);

  hsize_t size[1] = {1};
  hsize_t offset[1] = {0};
  dataspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, size, offset);

  dataset.write(v1.data(), array_type);

  return 0;
};
```

If I leave out the call to the `write` function the code creates an empty file with the following structure (as printed out by `h5dump`):

```
HDF5 "jarray.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "jarray" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_VLEN { H5T_IEEE_F32LE}
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 2 ) / ( 2 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): (), ()
      }
   }
}
}
```

This makes me believe the dataset has the correct structure but I'm not getting the writing part right.

Could someone clarify how to write to such an array? How would one go about reading the values back afterwards? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do this with HDF5 C++ API, but you could try [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it alleviates you from HDF5 low-level details. Using HDFql in C++, you could do the following to write/read an HDF5 jagged array:

```
// create HDF5 file 'jarray.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
HDFql::execute("CREATE AND USE FILE jarray.h5");

// create HDF5 dataset 'jarray' of one dimension (size 2) as a variable-length float (i.e. jagged)
HDFql::execute("CREATE DATASET jarray AS VARFLOAT(2)");

// write 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 in first row of dataset 'jarray', 0.4 and 0.5 in second row
HDFql::execute("INSERT INTO jarray VALUES((0.1, 0.2, 0.3), (0.4, 0.5))");

// read first row of dataset 'jarray' using an hyperslab and populate cursor with values
HDFql::execute("SELECT FROM jarray[0:::1]");

// display values of first row
while (HDFql::cursorNext() == HDFql::SUCCESS)
{
     std::cout << *HDFql::cursorGetFloat() << std::endl;
}

// read second row of dataset 'jarray' using an hyperslab and populate cursor with values
HDFql::execute("SELECT FROM jarray[1:::1]");

// display values of second row
while (HDFql::cursorNext() == HDFql::SUCCESS)
{
     std::cout << *HDFql::cursorGetFloat() << std::endl;
}
```

This is a short example based on direct writing of values. If you need to write/read using user-defined memory (i.e. a variable), please take a look at the [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and  [examples](http://www.hdfql.com/examples) to get additional information.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised there are no mentions to HDFql in the HDF5 documentation. This syntax is so much cleaner than the C/C++ API (and apparently better documented). For the time being I'll switch over to HDFql, although despite what the authors might claim, I'm a bit concerned efficiency won't be quite the same. If I ever manage to make the C++ version work I'll report back with a benchmark.

Comment: Efficiency shouldn't be an issue if you use user-defined memory (i.e. a variable) in HDFql instead of a cursor (like illustrated in the above example). Moreover, when working with big amounts of HDF5 data, I/O is the most costly which means that additional CPU that HDFql requires to interpret statements passed in function `HDFql::execute` can be neglected (since it has no practical effects on efficiency/performance overall).